# How do you bind the jQuery autocomplete plugin? On page ready or on input click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a header and I would like to add a Search field that users the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

How should I set this up given that users will use this feature rarely, ~5% of page views. Do I bind the jQuery autocomplete plugin on page ready? Or should I bind the autocomplete on Input field click not overload the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you already importing the Javascript for the autocomplete plugin in your headers? My understanding is that the big hit in Javascript for a page is in the downloading, unzipping, and loading of it into memory. If you've already got the Javascript for the autocomplete plugin downloading when the page loads (by including it in the headers) then I don't see the point of waiting to bind the call to it lazily. I don't think it will buy you much if anything.

I would try both approaches with a profiler, but my suspicion is that you'll see no difference between the two approaches unless jQuery is actually downloading the script with AJAX to load it for the binding, but that doesn't sound like what's going on, and I think that second hit to the website for the AJAX call would be more expensive than just downloading the Javascript for the autocomplete plugin in the first place and binding it when the page loads.

Also make sure that the plugin actually works as expected if you decide to bind it lazily. I suspect it will, but I can imagine cases where the plugin will not work properly if it's not ready to go by the time the person starts typing.